# How do I fix ValueError when doing nlp.add_pipe(LanguageDetector(), name='language_detector', last=True) with spacy 3

Tags: python, spacy, language-detection

Every time I run the following code I found on Kaggle, I get `ValueError`. This is because of new version v3 of **SpaCy**:

```
import scispacy
import spacy
import en_core_sci_lg
from spacy_langdetect import LanguageDetector

nlp = en_core_sci_lg.load(disable=["tagger", "ner"])
nlp.max_length = 2000000
nlp.add_pipe(LanguageDetector(), name='language_detector', last=True)
```

ValueError: [E966] `nlp.add_pipe` now takes the string name of the registered component factory, not a callable component. Expected string, but got <spacy_langdetect.spacy_langdetect.LanguageDetector object at 0x00000216BB4C8D30> (name: 'language_detector').

- If you created your component with `nlp.create_pipe('name')`: remove nlp.create_pipe and call `nlp.add_pipe('name')` instead.
- If you passed in a component like `TextCategorizer()`: call `nlp.add_pipe` with the string name instead, e.g. `nlp.add_pipe('textcat')`.
- If you're using a custom component: Add the decorator `@Language.component` (for function components) or `@Language.factory` (for class components / factories) to your custom component and assign it a name, e.g. `@Language.component('your_name')`. You can then run `nlp.add_pipe('your_name')` to add it to the pipeline.

I have installed these versions:

```
python_version : 3.8.5
spacy.version  : '3.0.3'
scispacy.version  :  '0.4.0'
en_core_sci_lg.version  :  '0.4.0'
```

Comment: Does this still break if you don't disable the tagger and the ner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way `add_pipe` works changed in v3; components have to be registered, and can then be added to a pipeline just using their name. In this case you have to wrap the LanguageDetector like so:

```
import scispacy
import spacy
import en_core_sci_lg
from spacy_langdetect import LanguageDetector

from spacy.language import Language

def create_lang_detector(nlp, name):
    return LanguageDetector()

Language.factory("language_detector", func=create_lang_detector)

nlp = en_core_sci_lg.load(disable=["tagger", "ner"])
nlp.max_length = 2000000
nlp.add_pipe('language_detector', last=True)
```

You can read more about how this works in [the spaCy docs](https://spacy.io/api/language#factory).

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. If that solved your problem, you can accept my answer by clicking the big gray checkmark to the left of it.

Comment: This gives an error `AttributeError: type object 'Language' has no attribute 'factory'`

Comment: Sounds like maybe you're using spaCy v2 Amanda?

Answer (score 10):

You can also use a `@Language.factory` decorator to achieve the same result with less code :

```py
import scispacy
import spacy
import en_core_sci_lg
from spacy_langdetect import LanguageDetector
from spacy.language import Language

@Language.factory('language_detector')
def language_detector(nlp, name):
    return LanguageDetector()

nlp = en_core_sci_lg.load(disable=["tagger", "ner"])
nlp.max_length = 2000000
nlp.add_pipe('language_detector', last=True)
```