# Unable to use Language Detector of spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am trying to implement language detector of spacy but failing to do it

```
import spacy
from spacy_langdetect import LanguageDetector
text = 'एएस लर्निंग में, सीखना कभी समाप्त नहीं होता है।'
@Language.component("LanguageDetector")
nlp.add_pipe('LanguageDetector')
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(text)
doc._.language
```

[image]

Comment: Please see this question for an example of how to use the language detector with spaCy 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66433496/value-error-nlp-add-pipelanguagedetector-name-language-detector-last-tru

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Value Error: nlp.add\_pipe(LanguageDetector(), name='language\_detector', last=True)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66433496/value-error-nlp-add-pipelanguagedetector-name-language-detector-last-tru)

Comment: I will try and let you know but my work has been done so, it's cool.